# Vtiger CRM #: How to write PHP code in log4php.properties file

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am new to Vtiger CRM. I want to write php code in log4php.properties file and also it need to be executed.

I can write the code but it is not executing at all. So kindly help me with a way which will allow to execute the file.

Also this need to be executed dynamic with separate domains.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open your index.php file from crm root directory and Add this code

```
function replace_string_in_a_file($filepath, $search, $replace) {
    if (@file_exists($filepath)) {

        $file = file($filepath);
        foreach ($file as $index => $string) {
            if (strpos($string, $search) !== FALSE)
                $file[$index] = "$replace\n";
        }
        $content = implode($file);
        return $content;
    }else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
$filepath = $root_directory . 'log4php.properties';
$search = 'log4php.appender.A1.File=';
$replace = 'log4php.appender.A1.File=' . DOMAIN_PATH . '/logs/vtigercrm.log';
$log_properties_content = replace_string_in_a_file($filepath, $search, $replace);

if (!empty($log_properties_content)) {
    file_put_contents($filepath, $log_properties_content);
}
```